# При объявлении объединения, содержащего ссылки, вылезает ошибка "no appropriate default constructor available"

Tags: c++, структуры, конструктор, объединение

```
struct BeginInfo
{
   int a;
};

struct LoadInfo
{
    FILE* pFile;
};

struct MoveInfo
{
    int a;
};

struct RotateInfo
{
    int a;
};

struct DrawInfo
{
    HDC hDC;
};

struct EndInfo
{
    int a;
};


union CommandInfo
{
    BeginInfo& beginInfo;
    LoadInfo& loadInfo;
    MoveInfo& moveInfo;
    RotateInfo& rotateInfo;
    DrawInfo& drawInfo;
    EndInfo& endInfo;
};
```

Comment: Объединение тут не при чем. Дело в том, что ссылка не может не указывать в никуда. При объявлении ссылки ее нужно сразу инициализировать. А в Вашем случае нет никакой инициализации. Вот компилятор и ругается.

Answer (score 1):

Разумеется. Дело в том, что `union` [не может](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union) содержать ссылки.

Но судя по сообщению об ошибке, проблема может быть где-то ещё.